# F1/AUC epoch-based metrics in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, auc

fellow community!

I have next problem: I want to evaluate my model after each epoch using **F1/AUC** or other related scores in **Keras**. I use Tensorflow as backend.

I have searched the internet, but didn't found anything meaningful that would create a picture of a solution.

Can anyone propose something? Do I need to write my custom **Sequence** generator? Right now I am using **ImageDataGenerator** to get images from folder 
in Google Drive.

Any answers are very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All of it is in [`tf.metrics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/metrics) which is aliased also as `tf.keras.metrics`. It's both in the new 2.0 API and in the [1.x API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics).

In particular, you will use classes:

- [AUC](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/AUC)
- [Precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/Precision) and [Recall](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/Recall) from wich you can compute the F1 score

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I know that these metrics are already implemented in both TF/Keras. But this is not my question.

My question is how to add these metrics to be calculated after each epoch, because right now it's trivial to add them for each batch. (One solution would be to make a batch of size of my dataset but it's rather a stupid solution, I guess)